# How to take screenshots on a Windows laptop?

Tags: laptop

I've been trying to take screenshots on my Toshiba Laptop.  When I do take them, I don't know how to access them. How do you access your screenshots? How can they be set as your background?

Comment: You can find many sources of documentation for this question.  The magic word is "screenshot" rather than "snapshot".

Comment: @ChristopherHostage you may be right, but I assumed he meant taking pictures from his laptops camera

Comment: @BlazingTrio , please Edit the question to confirm you mean taking snapshots out of the camera.  Just editing the title to say "camera snapshots" would make it unambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> button, that places a screenshot of your entire display in your clipboard. You would need to then paste that screenshot into a program like Paint and save it in the location of your choice. Then you can easily set that as the background by right-clicking the saved file and choose `Set as desktop background`.

An alternative to the <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> button -> paste in Paint workflow is to use the Snipping Tool program included with Windows. You can find it in the Start Menu under Windows Accessories, or by simply searching for it.

Comment: just to clarify, the PrtScn button works on a windows laptop? I've been using the windows button+G thing the laptop says to take snapshots, but when i click the snapshot button, the menu closes so i can't see where it went, or if it was taken at all. this was what i was talking about, but I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, the PrtScn button should work. The Snipping Tool will give you more options and flexibility. Win+G is the Game Bar, I have not personally used it for screenshots but you can find more info here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026387/windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts-for-game-bar